# How is R squared calculated in context to H.clustering?

Tags: clustering, statistics, r-squared

I was reading the paper ["Consistent Individualized Feature Attribution for Tree
Ensembles" by Scott Lundberg et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03888) and cannot understand how the calculation for the $R^2$ works here - see explanation on the image.

From this paper, the authors calculate an $R^2$ value based on the "proportion of model output variance explained". I fully understand how $R^2$ works regarding regression, but I'm not sure what the calculation looks like when used in this context.

Could someone explain to me what this calculation looks like?

[image]

Comment: Better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Agreed that this might be a better fit for Cross Validated

Comment: Thanks, will post there instead!